# Get total price in wishlist opencart

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I'm new IN opencart and I want show **total price** for each products and   **estimated total price** for all products and I'm see the controller for wishlist not provide total price.

This is code controller wishlist:

```
<?php
   class ControllerAccountWishList extends Controller {
    public function index() {
      if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
      $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', true);
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', true));
    }

    $this->load->language('account/wishlist');

    $this->load->model('account/wishlist');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    if (isset($this->request->get['remove'])) {
        // Remove Wishlist
        $this->model_account_wishlist->deleteWishlist($this->request->get['remove']);

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_remove');

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/wishlist'));
    }

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_account'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('account/account', '', true)
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('account/wishlist')
    );

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');

    $data['column_image'] = $this->language->get('column_image');
    $data['column_name'] = $this->language->get('column_name');
    $data['column_model'] = $this->language->get('column_model');
    $data['column_stock'] = $this->language->get('column_stock');
    $data['column_price'] = $this->language->get('column_price');
    $data['column_action'] = $this->language->get('column_action');

    $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');
    $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
    $data['button_remove'] = $this->language->get('button_remove');

    if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
        $data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];

        unset($this->session->data['success']);
    } else {
        $data['success'] = '';
    }

    $data['products'] = array();

    $results = $this->model_account_wishlist->getWishlist();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($result['product_id']);
        if ($product_info) {
            if ($product_info['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_wishlist_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_wishlist_height'));
            } else {
                $image = false;
            }
            if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
                $stock = $product_info['stock_status'];

            } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
                $stock = $product_info['quantity'];
            } else {
                $stock = $this->language->get('text_instock');
            }

            if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }

            if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
                $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $special = false;
            }

            $data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
                'thumb'      => $image,
                'name'       => $product_info['name'],
                'model'      => $product_info['model'],
                'stock'      => $stock,
                'price'      => $price,
                'special'    => $special,
                'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id']),
                'remove'     => $this->url->link('account/wishlist', 'remove=' . $product_info['product_id'])
            );
        } else {
            $this->model_account_wishlist->deleteWishlist($result['product_id']);
        }
    }

    $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', true);

    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
    $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
    $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('account/wishlist', $data));
}

public function add() {
    $this->load->language('account/wishlist');

    $json = array();

    if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = $this->request->post['product_id'];
    } else {
        $product_id = 0;
    }

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

    if ($product_info) {
        if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
            // Edit customers cart
            $this->load->model('account/wishlist');

            $this->model_account_wishlist->addWishlist($this->request->post['product_id']);

            $json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . (int)$this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('account/wishlist'));
            $json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), $this->model_account_wishlist->getTotalWishlist());
        } else {
            if (!isset($this->session->data['wishlist'])) {
                $this->session->data['wishlist'] = array();
            }

            $this->session->data['wishlist'][] = $this->request->post['product_id'];

            $this->session->data['wishlist'] = array_unique($this->session->data['wishlist']);

            $json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_login'), $this->url->link('account/login', '', true), $this->url->link('account/register', '', true), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . (int)$this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('account/wishlist'));

            $json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) ? count($this->session->data['wishlist']) : 0));
        }
    }

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
 }
}
```

Can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: Do you want to show products total prices in wishlist page?

Comment: yes i need show total price in wishlist

Answer (score 0):

To display total price in customer wishlist, open this file:

```
catalog/controller/account/wishlist.php
```

**Find:**

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
```

**Add before it:**

```
/* create a new variable and set it to zero*/
$total_price = 0;
```

**Find:**

```
if ($product_info) {
```

**Add after it:**

```
$total_price += $this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'],$product_info['tax_class_id'],$this->config->get('config_tax'));
```

**Find:**

```
$data['continue'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', true);
```

**Add before it:**

```
$data['total_price'] = $this->currency->format($total_price, $this->session->data['currency']);
```

now open your theme file:

```
catalog/view/theme/Your_theme/template/account/wishlist.tpl
```

Add this code where you want to show total:

```
<div>Total: <?php echo $total_price; ?></div>
```

I've tested this on Opencart 2.3.0.2